# Error running fauna FQL query from netlify function

Tags: netlify, faunadb, netlify-cli

I'm trying to run a query from a netlify function. The function is pretty simple, it just "upserts" a post:

```js
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  const faunadb = require('faunadb')

  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  }

  const q = faunadb.query
  const adminClient = new faunadb.Client({
    secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET,
  })

  const post = event.body

  const queryResult = await adminClient.query(
    q.If(
      q.Exists(q.Match(q.Index('post_uuid'), post.uuid)),
      q.Update(
        q.Select(['ref'], q.Get(q.Match(q.Index('post_uuid'), post.uuid))),
        { data: post }
      ),
      q.Create(q.Collection('posts'), { data: post })
    )
  )

  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers,
    body: '',
  })
}
```

The query works using Fauna's online shell and every other part of the script appears to be working but when I run the query I get this error and netlify CLI crashes:

```
Request from ::1: POST /.netlify/functions/savePost
{"level":"error","message":"End - Error:"}
{"errorMessage":"validation failed","errorType":"BadRequest","level":"error"}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    at formatLambdaLocalError (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\src\utils\serve-functions.js:25:100)
    at handleErr (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\src\utils\serve-functions.js:29:55)
    at Context.callbackHandler [as callback] (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\src\utils\serve-functions.js:60:14)
    at Context.done (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\lambda-local\build\lib\context.js:204:14)
    at Context.fail (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\lambda-local\build\lib\context.js:211:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    at formatLambdaLocalError (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\src\utils\serve-functions.js:25:100)
    at handleErr (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\src\utils\serve-functions.js:29:55)
    at Context.callbackHandler [as callback] (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\src\utils\serve-functions.js:60:14)
    at Context.done (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\lambda-local\build\lib\context.js:204:14)
    at Context.fail (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\lambda-local\build\lib\context.js:211:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)

C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\netlify-redirector\lib\redirects.js:116
      throw ex;
      ^
abort({}) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\netlify-redirector\lib\redirects.js:1070:13)
    at stackTrace (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\netlify-redirector\lib\redirects.js:1087:12)
    at process.abort (C:\Users\Oliver\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\netlify-redirector\lib\redirects.js:8502:44)
    at process.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:202:22)
    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:223:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:32)
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

I'm running this in `netlify dev`:

System
Windows 10
node: v15.4.0
netlify cli: v2.69.11

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was being an idiot! In case someone hits the same problem as me I'm just posting an answer to my own question.

First (not sure why) it seems you have to move

```js
const faunadb = require('faunadb')

const q = faunadb.query
const adminClient = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET,
})
```

outside of the function.

Second, the query was failing because the body of the request, what I called `post` is actually a string not an object (kinda obvious but I didn't notice it!). The query I was running required an object to be passed to either `Create` or `Update` and crashed because I was passing a string.

It's a bit annoying (maybe a bit of a bug?) but netlify crashes if the query returns a BadRequest.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you can also wrap the whole thing in a try/catch and return the error.

```js
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  const faunadb = require('faunadb')

  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  }

  const q = faunadb.query
  const adminClient = new faunadb.Client({
    secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET,
  })

  const post = event.body

  try {
    const queryResult = await adminClient.query(
        q.If(
        q.Exists(q.Match(q.Index('post_uuid'), post.uuid)),
        q.Update(
            q.Select(['ref'], q.Get(q.Match(q.Index('post_uuid'), post.uuid))),
            { data: post }
        ),
        q.Create(q.Collection('posts'), { data: post })
        )
    )

    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers,
        body: '',
    })
  } catch (error) {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(error),
    })
  }
}
```